# Jetpack Popup doesn't display full height when decorFitsSystemWindows is false

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

We are working on a feature on Android using Jeckpack Compose that need us to display an overlay over the whole screen and blur the background while we have some transparency areas to remark some parts of the UI and explain those UI components to the user.

To achieve this we are using a combinacion of `Popup` and `Canvas` API, and to be able use the whole screen height we are setting up `decorFitsSystemWindows` to `false`.

Pretty much everything is working as we want but we have an IU issue that we haven't been able to fix. The issue is that the `Popup` is not taking the full screen height instead it is leaving a white space at the bottom of the screen.

Here a sample code of what we are doing

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
      WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

      val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
      val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp
      val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

      val statusBarHeightDp = WindowInsets.systemBars.asPaddingValues().calculateTopPadding()
      val totalHeight = screenHeight + statusBarHeightDp

      val cornerRadius = CornerRadius(16f)

      val properties = PopupProperties(
        clippingEnabled = false,
        usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)

      Popup(
        properties = properties){
        Canvas(
          modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable {
            },
          onDraw = {
            val spotlightPath = Path().apply {
              addRoundRect(
                RoundRect(
                  rect = Rect(
                    offset = Offset(16f, 987f),
                    size = Size(1048f, 512f),
                  ),
                  cornerRadius = cornerRadius
                )
              )
            }
            clipPath(
              path = spotlightPath,
              clipOp = ClipOp.Difference
            ) {
              drawRect(
                brush = SolidColor(Color.Red),
                size = Size(screenWidth.toPx(), totalHeight.toPx())
              )
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see on the following image, there is a white space at the bottom of the screen that we don't want, we need to red overlay to take the whole screen height and width.

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqeiy.png)

Any idea about what may be happening?